# Django return custom HTTP status text

Tags: python, django, http

I'm trying to be compatible with an app-side bug(). I want to return a response with custom HTTP message
For example, I get `HTTP/1.1 429 TOO_MANY_REQUESTS` now, I want get `HTTP/1.1 429 CUSTOM_MESSAGE`
Howerver, I can get only `h2 200`

Comment: Why would you need to do this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What does this have to do with #django-rest-framework?

Comment: @Reez0    To fix bugs in already listed apps

Comment: @Andrew I'm using DRF in this project....

Answer (score 0):

Django has HttpResponse objects to build custom responses.

The following should do the trick:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

response = HttpResponse("CUSTOM MESSAGE", status=429, headers={"CUSTOM_MESSAGE": "..."})
```

see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/request-response/#id4

Comment: If I use HttpResponse "CUSTOM MESSAGE" will in the body, I want it in the http header

Comment: than just add this to the headers field  HttpResponse(status=429, headers={"CUSTOM_MESSAGE": "this is really too much to handle for my server. Please go away!"})

Edit: Updated the answer

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity what I said, I want to edit the content in http message header which looks like "OK" in "http1.1 200 OK", not the header like {"content-type": "text/html"}

Comment: It's called a `HTTP status code`. Google that, plenty of answers will be shown. You likely do not want to invent your own. Here is a list of statuscodes and their meanings: https://umbraco.com/knowledge-base/http-status-codes/ (scroll down)

Comment: Actually, my goal is editing the status text，textual description of the status code. Made it substandard for my particular needs,

Answer (score 0):

Updating HttpResponse.reason_phrase work for me, but HTTP/2.0 message will not show reason phrase, I could only find it in HTTP/1.1 message

see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.reason_phrase